# Proving recursive function complexity by induction

Tags: asymptotic-complexity, recurrence, induction

I need to prove by induction that for -

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + c2 , T(1) = c1 

The run time complexity is - T(n) = O(n)
```

In my induction step after the base case and the induction assumption  I wrote that -

```
T(k+1) = T(k) + c2 = O(k) + c2 = O(k + 1)
```

but for proving this run time complexity I need to show that there exist 
C,N0 > 0 so the final inequality true.

If someone can tell me how to find/or correct my induction.
Thanks.

Comment: Eh, `O(k) + c2 = O(k+1)` in view of the additional `+`

Answer (score 2):

To prove by induction, you have to do three steps.

> 1. define proposition `P(n)` for n
> 2. show `P(n_0)` is true for base case `n_0`
> 3. assume that `P(k)` is true and show `P(k+1)`is also true

it seems that you don't have concrete definition of your `P(n)`.

so Let `P(n) := there exists constant c(>0) that T(n) <= c*n.`

and your induction step will be like this:

assume that `P(k)`is true. then `P(k+1) = T(k) + c2`

by `P(k)`, `there exists constant c_k(>0) that T(k) <= c_k*k`.

so `T(k+1) = T(k) + c2 <= c_k*k + c2 <= (c_k+1)*k + (c_k+1) = (c_k+1)*(k+1)` (if we choose `c_k+1 = max(c_k, c2)`)

so `P(k+1)`is true.

therefore these proves by induction that

`for every n > n_0=1, there exists constant c(>0) that T(n) <= c*n.`

> *P.S.* [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_chap03.pdf) you can get some readings on induction. and also, at MIT OCW, the course [6042J](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/index.htm) provides nice lecture for induction and strong induction you can practice and get intuition.